# How to re-arrange UI Elements when screen is rotated

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am building an iphone app that has a small button at the right corner of the screen. Ideally, I should be able to see the button no matter what orientation I hold the phone. However, for now I can only see the button when the screen is upright/vertical, when I turn it sideways, the button is not visible.

What is the easiest way to solve this problem? Can I move the button manually when I rotate the screen ( this may be easier since the button is the only IB OUlet that is not showing up correctly, other elements are fine).

Or I thought of making two different views with two different nib files. ( But I am not sure how to do that?)

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried autoresizing mask from IB????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in interface builder, you should be able to specify which corner the button should stick to, in the button's properties.
that's the easiest way. if you have a more complex interface then you'd need to either write code to move the button, or as you say, create a new view for the "other" orientation.

Comment: Search for springs and struts! With them you can specify that an element should always stick to the top right (or whatever)

Comment: I didn't have the screen in front of me when I wrote the answer, but thanks to @Julian, I found this other comment that should take you to the right place: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342082/sizing-a-control-to-fit-its-container-in-interface-builder/345676#345676

Answer (score 0):

Redrawing the frame of the buttons in willRotateToInterfaceOrientation fixes the issue. or for just rotating and make use of autoresizingmask